# Bash difference of optional parameters equal sign '--stuff=42' or not '--stuff 42'

Tags: bash, unix

I often see commands that set value of optional parameter with =, and sometimes a plain space. What it is called ?

Example of both commands that works :

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
```

and

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service http
```

What is the difference between of using the equal sign or not ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, from what I understand 

<< ... sometimes it must follow an '=' sign. POSIX doesn't support optional arguments meaningfully (the POSIX getopt() only allows them for the last option on the command line). >>

it prevents POSIX's getopt from breaking apart --add-service and http, so it gets splitted('=') manually later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a formal name for this; I usually call `--foo=bar` "explicit" and `--foo bar` "implicit", because in the latter case you'd have to know how it's implemented to tell whether it means "set the *string option* `foo` to 'bar'" or "set the *boolean option* `foo` to `true` and pass the *argument* 'bar'".

Following the very sensible Python saying that "explicit is better than implicit" I always prefer `--foo=bar`.